# Adding Jersey Configuration disables register view controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jersey

i am using springboot 1.5.2 and i am using jersey and jsf

i have mapping for default view / as follows:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter defaultView() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/faces/public/login.xhtml");
                registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
                super.addViewControllers(registry);
            }
        };
    }
```

before i added jersey configuration, it was working fine, and after i added the following jersey configuration it stopped working:

```
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(MyService.class);
    }
}
```

when i remove the JerSeyConfig class, the mapping works fine, but when i add it, the mapping stops working, please advise how to make them both working together fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

- Annotate `JerseyConfig` with `@Component` instead of `@Configuration` and make sure package is being scanned via `@ComponentScan` in main class.
- Make sure `Spring` MVC dispatcher servlet is mapped to a path different than `Jersey` servlet's, for instance:

  # Spring MVC dispatcher servlet path. Needs to be different than Jersey's to enable/disable Actuator endpoints access (/info, /health, ...)

  server.servlet-path: /

  # Jersey dispatcher servlet

  spring.jersey.application-path: /api

More details could be found at my blog post: [Microservices using Spring Boot, Jersey, Swagger and Docker](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/04/05/Microservices-using-Spring-Boot-Jersey-Swagger-and-Docker.html)